# Can I add a tableview to a view with other controls?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Can I add a tableview to an existing view in interface builder.

My interfaces builder looks like the following

[image]

But when I run the code in the simulator you can see the table is not shown in the same place as in interface builder as it overlays the buttons at the bottom ???

[image]

**UPDATE ...** I am sort of making progress but the buttons at the bottom are hidden ??

[image]

**FIXED...** with the following code as advised :)

```
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];

view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIButton *buttonA = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
buttonA.frame = CGRectMake(101,5,118,29);
[buttonA setTitle:@"Save & Exit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
buttonA.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

[view addSubview:buttonA];

UIButton *buttonB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
buttonB.frame = CGRectMake(254,5,56,29);
[buttonB setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
buttonB.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

[view addSubview:buttonB];

return view;
```

}

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 40;
```

}

Comment: May be because of auto alignment.

Comment: Not sure but check out autosizing for your tableview.

Comment: Yes You can, and guess what you have already did that :). Rest is just Unpin the bottom and add streaching in your tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

in the datasource method return the Footer view (The UIView which contain "save & edit" and "next" UIButtons).

Comment: I am not sure what need to do with this method ??? I have updated my question with the latest screenshot - as you can see - the buttons are hidden for some reason ?

Comment: create a UIView and add the buttons to that view object and return in the method which i mentioned. try it out.. and see.

Comment: this method is a UITableViewDataSource methods and it's fire when the the create the section footer for the relevant section.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have attached the delegate and datasource of tableview to file owner. Also you have to implement atleast these two methods.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

[Check this link for example!](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply autosizing to those subviews in .xib file as following as....

[image]

or

you can change programatically using the following functions..

```
UIViewAutoresizing
Specifies how a view is automatically resized.

enum {
   UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
```

The example is:

```
  [yourViews.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth];
```